# using nested query to insert values into a table

Tags: sql

how to insert values selected from another table using nested query

Comment: What database system (RDBMS) are you using?  What are the tables you want to query and the table you want to insert to?

Answer (score 2):

may be following will help you :

```
INSERT california_authors (au_id, au_lname, au_fname)
SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE State = 'CA'
```

more : [Using INSERT and SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263.aspx)